# RubyMine wrong slashes in configuration

Tags: vagrant, rubymine

I'm on Win 8 with vagrant on virtualbox running precise32.
I created remote SDK and deployment config mapped to virtual machine, and it works fine except one little thing - slashes are not in the right direction.

I created a Gem configuration with following params:
gem name: guard
executable name: guard
rest is by default

When I try to run this gem commmand I get the following:

> /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
>   /home/vagrant/.rubymine_helpers/rb/exec_with_work_dir.rb
>   /home/vagrant/dev/fruitad
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby -e
>   '$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)'
>   **\home\vagrant.rvm\rubies\ruby-2.0.0-p195\bin\guard**
>
> -e:1:in `load': cannot load such file -- homevagrant.rvmrubiesruby-2.0.0-p195binguard (LoadError)     from -e:1:in`
>   '

You see, path to the gemfile with wrong slashes.

It is my fault? Maybe I should configure something else to get it working? Or it is some RubyMine bug?

Comment: [Contact support](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home/) with the screenshots of your deployment, remote SDK and mappings configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug, reported at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13996.